# Reflection and constructors with interface argument

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to modify a private field inside a class, which has a constructor taking interface as an argument. I am having trouble instantiating such a class (it throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: wrong number of arguments). Now the code stripped to the most important details is as follows:

Here is my reflection code to inject different boolean value (unique field is true by default I want false there):

```
private void modifySitePatterns() {

    try {

        Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();
        ClassLoader classLoader = thread.getContextClassLoader();
        Class<?> classToModify = Class.forName(
                "dr.evolution.alignment.SitePatterns", true, classLoader);
        Constructor<?>[] constructors = classToModify
                .getDeclaredConstructors();
        Field[] fields = classToModify.getDeclaredFields();

        Object classObj = constructors[0].newInstance(new Object[] {}); //this throws the exception

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (fields[i].getName() == "unique") {
                System.out.println(i);
                fields[i].setAccessible(true);
                fields[i].set(classObj, false);

            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}// END: modifySitePatterns()
```

Here is the class I'm trying to modify:

```
public class SitePatterns implements SiteList, dr.util.XHTMLable {

//omitted

private boolean unique = true;

 public SitePatterns(Alignment alignment) {// constructor 0
    this(alignment, null, 0, 0, 1);
   }

}
```

And the argument that is giving me trouble:

```
public interface Alignment extends SequenceList, SiteList {

   //omitted

public abstract class Abstract implements Alignment {

}

//omitted

}
```

How should I proceed with passing a fake argument to the instance of the constructor?

Comment: You'd be better off using `getDeclaredConstructor(Class...)`.  It looks like you're trying to find a no-arg constructor, but you don't show one.

Comment: @Michael: getDeclaredConstructors() gets all Constructors for this Class, no-arg included.  But I do agree, it is best to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

(Probably obvious)  You need to pass in an Alignment.
If you don't have a non-abstract subclass to instantiate, I think you'll need to make a dummy one.

Answer (score 0):

You currently have no concrete implementation that you have shown us.

```
//anonymous implementation
Object classObj = constructors[0].newInstance(new Alignment() {
    //alignment implementation...
});

//or concrete implementation
Object classObj = constructors[0].newInstance(new AlignmentImpl());
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment indicating to use `getDeclaredConstructors()` is correct, be specific about which one you want since it has (at least) 2 from what your code is showing.

To instantiate your class, you'll need an instance of some class that implements your `Alignment` interface.  Construct that first, then pass it to the `newInstance` method on the constructor.